# Replace in strings found by grep

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I have a lot of files, where i need to replace ':' with ' -' in some strings.

I found all the strings i need with grep: `grep -G '^ \* @' datapath/ -r` but now I need to replace all ':' in this strings with ' -' and I don't know how.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) command. In short, you will have use it like this:

```
for file in datapath/*.file; do
    sed s/"^ \* @"/-/g $file > $file.new
done
```

Comment: It's the answer, but I need to save replaces in the same file so I use -i flag and don't use '> $file.new'

Comment: I didn't provide a solution which modifies the original files just in case something goes wrong:). Anyway, I'm gladly that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

grep cannot do substitution.

try this:

```
sed '/^ \* @/s/:/-/g' datapath/*.file
```

Comment: it works, but it doesn't automatically resaves the file with new symbols.

Answer (score 0):

[find/replace with perl](http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2005/08/18/perl-oneliner-recursive-search-and-replace/) : perl -pi -e 's/original string/new string/' filename

```
perl -pi -e 's/:/-/' *
```

Comment: It replaces all the ':', not only in strings I need.